# .net<->Java text encoding works in development environment but fails at "production"

Tags: java, vb.net, ipc

I send the following byte array from a Java application to a Vb.Net one:

```
byte[] buffer = "<CMD>{§}SETUP US THE BOMB".getBytes("UTF-16LE");
```

Below is how the Vb.Net side parses the array into a String:

```
Dim result as String = (New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding(False, False)).GetString(buffer)
```

After that I log the resulting string to the console (the byte dumps are done at VB.Net as they arrive):

```
HEX: 60 0 67 0 77 0 68 0 62 0 123 0 167 0 125 0 83 0 69 0 84 0 85 0 80 0 32 0 85 0 83 0 32 0 84 0 72 0 69 0 32 0 66 0 79 0 77 0 66 0
STR: <CMD>{§}SETUP US THE BOMB
```

The received byte array is different if I don't use eclipse and the encoding seems somehow broken...

```
HEX: 60 0 67 0 77 0 68 0 62 0 123 0 239 0 191 0 189 0 125 0 83 0 69 0 84 0 85 0 80 0 32 0 85 0 83 0 32 0 84 0 72 0 69 0 32 0 66 0 79 0 77 0 66 0
STR: <CMD>{ï¿½}SETUP US THE BOMB
```

Looks like something happens at Java side when i switch from development to actual use of the code.

The byte array is sent locally to the Vb.Net application using an Udp transport.

I'm using plain java.net.datagramsocket to do the communication.

*Update*

I tried getting log the array from Java too, as i thought it could be helpful:

> [D]=Development [P]=Production [J]=Java [R]=Received by Vb.Net
>
> [D][J]: 60 0 67 0 77 0 68 0 62 0 123 0 **-89** 0 125 0  83 0 69...
>
> [D][R]: 60 0 67 0 77 0 68 0 62 0 123 0 **167** 0 125 0  83 0 69...
>
> [P][J]: 60 0 67 0 77 0 68 0 62 0 123 0 **-17** 0 **-65** 0 **-67** 0 125 0 83 0 69...
>
> [P][R]: 60 0 67 0 77 0 68 0 62 0 123 0 **239** 0 **191** 0 **189** 0 125 0 83 0 69...

Something is definitely wrong, as if the string is re-encoded prior to sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally track down the problem to the fact that I'm using an external tool (gradle) that does not treat  my *.java files as UTF-8/16 (as eclipse does) but as Latin/windows/something else and the "§" literal is then not escaped.

**To solve this I had to escape "§" to "\u00A7"**.

PS. I think some configuration trick in gradle would allow to skip escaping but as I do not entirely control the development environment I did not investigate this further.

Comment: That actually was the thing I wanted to ask you to check... In your IDE there should be an option somewhere to change that default file encoding.

Comment: @SuperPeanut I investigated it more. I am currently using Eclipse and found only this: http://i.imgur.com/q51WnyS.png Changing the encoding values does not seem to affect the outcome. After all I'm happy now so I will mark my answer as the solution once the time limit (now 24h) is elapsed.

Comment: In your picture there is a combobox saying "Text File Encoding-->Other", what are the options there?

Comment: It has ISO-88591 Cp1252 ASCII and various UTF encodings. I tried to set that to Utf-8 and the vb.net app received it along with other gibberish. I think gradle is the problem as in eclipse the § character works normally...

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a proper comment, but it's not really an answer...

I have tried to encode the string in VB .NET and I don't have the same bytes as you do :

```
Dim buf As Byte()
buf = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes("<CMD>{§}SETUP US THE BOMB")
```

which results in :

> 60 0 67 0 77 0 68 0 62 0 123 0 **167 0** 125 0 83 0 69 0 84 0 85 0 80 0 32 0 85 0 83 0 32 0 84 0 72 0 69 0 32 0 66 0 79 0 77 0 66 0

while your buffer from Java is :

> 60 0 67 0 77 0 68 0 62 0 123 0 **239 0 191 0 189 0** 125 0 83 0 69 0 84 0 85 0 80 0 32 0 85 0 83 0 32 0 84 0 72 0 69 0 32 0 66 0 79 0 77 0 66 0

So I would say the issue comes from the Java encoding as that character should output as two hexa number and not six...